# WCF: set CustomBinding to Transport Only Security in code

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-security

We use a customBinding in our project, and I want to set it Transport Only Security in the code, which should be equivalent to XML as bellow :

```
<security mode="Transport" />
```

I searched a lot but I don't find how to do it, because my `CustomBinding` class extends `System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding` so there is no field security.

Also I'm looking for the equivalent in code to the below xml:

```
<message algorithmSuite="Basic128/Basic192/Basic256/Basic128Rsa15/Basic256Rsa15/TripleDes/TripleDesRsa15/Basic128Sha256/Basic192Sha256/TripleDesSha256/Basic128Sha256Rsa15/Basic192Sha256Rsa15/Basic256Sha256Rsa15/TripleDesSha256Rsa15"
         clientCredentialType="Certificate/IssuedToken/None/UserName/Windows"
         establishSecurityContext="Boolean"
         negotiateServiceCredential="Boolean" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `httpsTransport` for example

```
<httpsTransport authenticationScheme="Basic"  manualAddressing="true" maxReceivedMessageSize="524288000" transferMode="Streamed" />
```

More info [check](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/wcf/httpstransport)

Answer (score 0):

For Transport security mode in Custom binding, we usually use HttpsTransport section to configure.
For message security, it is implemented by the security section.
Please refer to the below configuration.

```
<customBinding>
        <binding name="wss-username-binary">
          <transactionFlow/>
          <security
      authenticationMode="SecureConversation"
      messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity11WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10">
            <secureConversationBootstrap
      authenticationMode="UserNameForSslNegotiated"
      messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity11WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10" />
          </security>
          <binaryMessageEncoding />
          <httpsTransport/>
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
```

For the authentication mode in WCF, please refer to the below document.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/securitybindingelement-authentication-modes
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

**Updated.**

```
 //Under the WCF service created by the below binding, server provides a certificate to ensure the message security, and the client provides a username/password to represent an identity
        var b = SecurityBindingElement.CreateUserNameForCertificateBindingElement();
        TextMessageEncodingBindingElement encoding = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement();
        HttpsTransportBindingElement transport = new HttpsTransportBindingElement();
        CustomBinding binding = new CustomBinding(b, encoding, transport);
```

Comment: Hi, I want to use code instead of XML, is that possible ?

Comment: No problem. Here is a simple custom binding with https feature.
TextMessageEncodingBindingElement encoding = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement();
            HttpsTransportBindingElement transport = new HttpsTransportBindingElement();
            CustomBinding binding = new CustomBinding(encoding, transport);
Message security is accomplished by the derived class of the SecurityBindingElement abstract class. we need to add an additional binding element to the constructor of the custom binding, just like the element in the mentioned document.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/securitybindingelement-authentication-modes

Comment: please refer to the below link. programmatically return a custom binding. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.channels.custombinding.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/extending/creating-user-defined-bindings